# How to echo out a post url within a src attribute as background image in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a conditional statement that checks to see if a post has a thumbnail, and if so, echos out a div that has the post thumbnail as the background image.

```
<?php if( the_post_thumbnail() )  {
    echo '
    
    <div class="post-hero" style="background-image: url(' . wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ');">';

    '</div>';

};?>
```

The problem is that my editor (vsCode) is throwing an error: an unexpected echo. I'm thinking it has to do with the second `echo` within the url.

I've tried changing `echo` to `print`, but that didn't work as well.

I'm stuck, and I'm new to PHP programming. Anything glaring in my code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a error in your echo string and `the_post_thumbnail()` needs to be replaced by `has_post_thumbnail()`. See this fixed version:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail() )
    echo '<div class="post-hero" style="background-image: url(\'' . wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)). '\');"></div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the error, but it's not echoing out the HTML. All I'm getting out of this code is `<img class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image"`, not the HTML before it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the `has_post_thumbnail()` condition.

Answer (score 0):

There were two errors in my code, one answered by @Amacado, and I changed

```
if( the_post_thumbnail() )
```

to

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() )
```

It worked then. Thanks!

Comment: I will edit my answer to include this hint, so this thread answer inherits all :)